# Autohotkey ToolTip Refresh

Tags: autohotkey

I can't get the tooltip to update once I input variables through the GUI to display.

Could someone please run this script? You use the pause key to get up the menu that edits the tooltip.

The problem is I cannot get the tooltip to update. The tooltip is displayed with some code that I don't understand. I found it another thread that helps immensely in stopping the flickering on the tooltip.

```
edit9 = pre-saved F9
edit10 = pre-saved F10
edit11 = pre-saved F11
edit12 = pre-saved F12

ToolTip,F1: %edit1%`r`nF2: %edit2%`r`nF3: %edit3%`r`nF4: %edit4%`r`nF5: %edit5%`r`nF6: %edit6%`r`nF7: %edit7%`r`nF8: %edit8%`r`nF9 Databit: %edit9%`r`nF10 Geeks: %edit10%`r`nF11 ASI: %edit11%`r`nF12 Integrated  Comp Sys: %edit12%, %mouseX%, %mouseY%, %mouseX%, %mouseY%
Gui, Destroy

Process,Exist
hwnd:=WinExist("ahk_class tooltips_class32 ahk_pid " Errorlevel)
Loop
   ToolTip_UpdatePos(hwnd)

ToolTip_UpdatePos(hwnd,x="",y=""){
   static TTM_TRACKPOSITION := 0x412
   VarSetCapacity(xc, 20, 0), xc := Chr(20),DllCall("GetCursorInfo", "Uint", &xc)
   ,yc := NumGet(xc,16), xc := NumGet(xc,12),xc+=30,yc+=30
   If x
      xc:=x
   If y
      yc:=y
   DllCall("SendMessage", A_PtrSize ? "UPTR" : "UInt", hwnd
                                    , "Uint", TTM_TRACKPOSITION
                                    , A_PtrSize ? "UPTR" : "UInt", 0
                                    , A_PtrSize ? "UPTR" : "UInt", (xc & 0xFFFF)|(yc & 0xFFFF)<<16)
}

Pause::
GUI, destroy ;2nd loop will crash w/o this
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ;Window must start with certain text
WinGetText, OutputVar, ConnectWise ; <--- A is active window
;msgbox %OutputVar%

gui, font, s10, Verdana
Gui, Add, Text, x6 y6 w150 h30, Text to display:

Gui, Add, Text, x6 y36 w150 h30, F1
Gui, Add, Edit, vedit1 x6 y56 w150 h25

Gui, Add, Text, x6 y86 w150 h30, F2
Gui, Add, Edit, vedit2 x6 y106 w150 h25

Gui, Add, Text, x6 y136 w150 h30, F3
Gui, Add, Edit, vedit3 x6 y156 w150 h25

Gui, Add, Text, x6 y186 w150 h30, F4
Gui, Add, Edit, vedit4 x6 y206 w150 h25

Gui, Add, Text, x6 y236 w150 h30, F5
Gui, Add, Edit, vedit5 x6 y256 w150 h25

Gui, Add, Text, x6 y286 w150 h30, F6
Gui, Add, Edit, vedit6 x6 y306 w150 h25

Gui, Add, Text, x6 y336 w150 h30, F7
Gui, Add, Edit, vedit7 x6 y356 w150 h25

Gui, Add, Text, x6 y386 w150 h30, F8
Gui, Add, Edit, vedit8 x6 y406 w150 h25

Gui, Add, Button, x61 y436 w40 h30, Ok

Gui, Show,, CW Info
return

buttonok:
gui, submit
return

F1::
SendPlay %edit1%
return

F2::
SendPlay %edit2%
return

F3::
SendPlay %edit3%
return

F4::
SendPlay %edit4%
return

F5::
SendPlay %edit5%
return

F6::
SendPlay %edit6%
return

F7::
SendPlay %edit7%
return

F8::
SendPlay %edit8%
return

F9::
SendPlay %edit9%
return

F10::
SendPlay %edit10%
return

F11::
SendPlay %edit11%
return

F12::
SendPlay %edit12%
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the tootip updating in the gui button subroutine

```
buttonok:
gui, submit
ToolTip,F1: %edit1%`r`nF2: %edit2%`r`nF3: %edit3%`r`nF4: %edit4%`r`nF5: %edit5%`r`nF6: %edit6%`r`nF7: %edit7%`r`nF8: %edit8%`r`nF9 Databit: %edit9%`r`nF10 Geeks: %edit10%`r`nF11 ASI: %edit11%`r`nF12 Integrated  Comp Sys: %edit12%
return
```

Something like that

Hope it helps